# Targeting specific columns in a csv file with python

Tags: python

I have the following python code. I want to compare two csv files, however I want to compare just 2 columns from the second CSV file.

How can i extend the below code to target just the columns 'ID' and 'Name' from the productsOld file?

```
import ctypes  # An included library with Python install.
def Mbox(title, text, style):
    return ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, text, title, style)

try:
    with open('pipeNew2.csv', 'r') as t1, open('productsOld.csv', 'r') as t2:
        fileone = t1.readlines()
        filetwo = t2.readlines()



    with open('update.csv', 'w') as outFile:
        for line in filetwo:
            if line not in fileone:
                outFile.write(line)
    Mbox('Complete', 'Compairson Complete', 0)
except (ValueError,IOError) as err:
        Mbox('Error',(str(err)),0)
```

What I've tried-this just prints out all the files anyway and just on the same row

```
import ctypes  # An included library with Python install.
import csv
def Mbox(title, text, style):
    return ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, text, title, style)

try:
    with open('pipeNew2.csv', 'r') as t1, open('productsOld.csv', 'r') as t2:
        fileone = t1.readlines()
        filetwo = t2.readlines()



    with open('update.csv', 'w') as outFile:
        newFile = csv.DictReader(filetwo)
        for row in newFile:
            if row['id'] not in fileone:
                outFile.write(str(row))
    Mbox('Complete', 'Compairson Complete', 0)
except (ValueError,IOError) as err:
        Mbox('Error',(str(err)),0)
```

[image: pipeNew2.csv]
[image: productsOld.csv]

Comment: take a look at `pandas` framework. you can read two csv files into two dataframes, manipulate them and write back. It's **a lot** faster than pure `for` loops.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) built-in module.

Example:

```
import ctypes  # An included library with Python install.
import csv


def Mbox(title, text, style):
    return ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, text, title, style)


try:
    f1n = 'pipeNew2.csv'
    fn1 = ['catalogid', 'id', 'name']

    f2n = 'productsOld.csv'
    fn2 = ['id', 'name']

    with open(f1n, 'r', newline='') as t1, open(f2n, 'r', newline='') as t2:
        f1 = [line['id'] + line['name'] for line in csv.DictReader(t1, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fn1)]
        f2 = csv.DictReader(t2, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fn2)

        with open('update.csv', 'w+', newline='') as outFile:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(outFile, fieldnames=fn2)
            writer.writeheader()  # if csv have header

            for oldRow in f2:
                if not oldRow['id'] + oldRow['name'] in f1:
                    writer.writerow(oldRow)

except (ValueError, IOError) as err:
    Mbox('Error', (str(err)), 0)
```

productsOld.csv

```
id,name
1,aa
2,bb
3,cc
4,dd
```

pipeNew2.csv

```
catalogid,id,name
a,1,aa
b,2,bb
c,4,dd
```

update.csv

```
id,name
3,cc
```

Comment: Right, so, the csv module helps you with the "targeting specific columns" part of your question - if you run both `fileone` and `file2` through one of the csv readers, it will take care of column separation for you.

But, that still leaves the part where you need to decide if the rows match. What are you expecting here? Are you comparing rows in the same positions, or are some rows missing from one or other file, or might the rows be in any order? It might be easier to see some examples.

Comment: I have updated the OP. So the first picture is the pipeNew file and the other productsOld. As you can see they are roughly in the same order, but rows might be missing, productsOld as also an extra column as well as the names all have punctuation in them which pipeNew does not have. All i want is to be able to run the program and for it to update a new file with the products that productsOld has that pipeNew doesn't.